# If $T$ is a bounded linear operator from $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ to $L^q(\mathbb{R})$ and $T$ is non-zero, then $p \leq q$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I'm a student in a Fourier Analysis class with a broad background in Functional Analysis. When this question was posed to me, I wasn't sure how to begin. Poking around, I looked at $L^p$ embeddings but $T$ may not be injective into $L^q$. Trying to solve this problem naively, I considered $f$ to have $L^p$ norm 1 (the sphere) and considered $$(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |Tf(x)|^q)^{\frac{1}{q}} \leq C  $$ where $C$ is the norm of $T$. Can I "normalize" T and assume $C=1$ to get rid of that $\frac{1}{q}$ exponent. How would $f$ having norm 1 help me here?

Edit: Would it be possible to "mod out" by the kernel of $T$ and consider that as an injective linear operator from $\frac{L^p(\mathbb{R}) }{kerT}$ to $L^q(\mathbb{R})$? I don't think I'd be able to use any embedding results here though.

Comment: What did the question _really_ ask?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich the question asked if the title proposition was true or not. Given Robert's answer, I should have included this.

Comment: For future reference: Actually you should have stated the problem correctly regardless of Robert's answer! As a general rule you shouldn't ask us to prove P unless you have a good reason to think P is true; otherwise you risk wasting people's time...

Comment: I understand. I'll try to make my questions more complete, as it probably would have helped me be more skeptical of the proposition as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, this is not true at all.  For example, let $\phi$ be any bounded linear functional on $L^p$, $g$ any nonzero member of 
$L^q$, and define $T f = \phi(f) g$.  That defines a nonzero bounded linear operator from $L^p(\mathbb R)$ into $L^q(\mathbb R)$.  Perhaps the assumption was supposed to
be that $T$ is injective?

Comment: Even injectivity fails to make the statement true, no? Take $w(x)=\exp(-x^2)$ and consider $T: L^\infty \to L^1$, $Tf(x) = w(x)f(x)$. Then $\Vert Tf\Vert_{L^1} \le \sqrt{\pi} \Vert f\Vert_{L^\infty}$, and $Tf = 0$ iff $f=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Robert!